# 3D Plot of Matrix with bars, overlayed with empty bars

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am trying to plot a matrix with bars, and show what the perfect case would give in the form of non-filled bars. The bars I was able to create:

```
data = {{0.002, 0, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.003`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.0023`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.001`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`,0.`, 0.`, 0.25`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.3`, 0.`, 0.`, 0, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,0, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.01`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.20, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.010, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,0.`, 0.`, 0.0021, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.002, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.02, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.2, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.2,0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.1, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.005, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,  0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,0.`, 0.001, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.0020`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.2, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.30, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.00, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.000}};

data3D = Join @@ MapIndexed[Append[#2, #] &, data, {2}];

col = {0.5, 0.2, 0.5};
bar[n_][{x_, y_, z_}] := {Opacity[1], Hue[((Sqrt[y^2 + x^2])/(3 Length[data])) + .14], Cuboid[{x - n, y - n, 0}, {x + n, y + n, z}]}

image = Graphics3D[bar[0.3] /@ data3D, Axes -> True, Ticks -> {{{1, ""}}, None, {0, .1, .2, .3, {.35, ""}}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .6}, Boxed -> False, FaceGrids -> {{{-1, 0, 0}, {{0.3, 18.7}, {0, .1, .2, .3, .35}}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {{0, 18.7}, {0, .1, .2, .3, .35}}}, {{0, 0, -1}, {{0.3, 18.7}, {0.3, 18.7}}}}]
```

[image: picture output]

What I would like is that the filled bars are overlayed with with unfilled bars. One wonderful example can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHfVj.png).

How can one add these unfilled bars? (In my example, they should all go up to 0.4.).

And optionally: In [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHfVj.png), there are color codes outside the actual matrix (grey + blue/red/green/violet). How can that be done?

Comment: Which bars exactly would you like to have with your styling on, just the outliners?

Comment: I am extremely disappointed to find that Mathematica has included `BarChart3D` to achieve precisely this sort of outcome, but for some reason, one cannot combine `ChartLayout->{"Stacked","Grid"}` as one would expect. In the future, I suspect this type of feature will be available and automatic, so that you would simply type `BarChart3D[data,ChartLayout->{"Stacked","Grid"}]` to produce the chart you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the unfilled bars can be done with a simple modification to your `bars` function.

All this does is to draw another cuboid on top of any bar that is taller than some arbitrary cut off (0.1), and include an `Opacity[0]` to make it unfilled.

```
(* your current bar function *)

bar[n_][{x_, y_, z_}] := {Opacity[1], Hue[((Sqrt[y^2 + x^2])/(3 Length[data])) + .14], Cuboid[{x - n, y - n, 0}, {x + n, y + n, z}]}

(* my modified bar function *)

bar[n_][{x_, y_, z_}] := {Opacity[1], Hue[((Sqrt[y^2 + x^2])/(3 Length[data])) + .14], Cuboid[{x - n, y - n, 0}, {x + n, y + n, z}], If[z > 0.1, {Opacity[0], Cuboid[{x - n, y - n, z}, {x + n, y + n, 0.4}]}]}
```

[image: plot with unfilled bars]

I didn't write a solution for adding the colour codes outside the matrix, but they could be done by drawing `Polygon[...]`'s in the right places with the right colours.

Comment: Another possibility is afforded by `{FaceForm[], Cuboid[(* stuff *)]}`.

Comment: Ah of course, overlaying two plots. That didn't occure to me. Thank you! Furthermore, why is your graphics so much nicer than mine?

Comment: hmm, I exported the plot with a higher resolution than the default:  `Export["image.png",(*the plot*),ImageResolution->300]`. I'm also running version 10. They changed the default plotting styles in V10 so that might account for other differences.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `BarChart3D` with a custom `ChartElementFunction` and appropriate options to get the same result:

```
ClearAll[cef]
cef[cedf_: "Cube", opacity_: Opacity[0]] := ({#3[[1]], ChartElementData[cedf][##], 
   If[#[[3, 2]] > .1, {FaceForm[opacity], 
    ChartElementData[cedf][{#[[1]], #[[2]], {#[[3, 2]], .4}}, ##2]}, {}]} &);
```

Use the color information as metadata:

```
datameta = MapIndexed[# -> Hue[((Sqrt[#2[[2]]^2 + #2[[1]]^2])/(3 Length[data])) + .14] &, 
  data, {2}];
```

Use `BarChart3D` with a `"Grid"` layout:

```
BarChart3D[datameta, ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
 Method -> "Canvas" -> False, BarSpacing -> {.1, .1}, 
 FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cef[]]
```

[image]

Use `BarSpacing -> {.5, .5}` to get

[image]

Use `ChartElementFunction -> cef["ProfileCube", Opacity[.2]]` to get

[image]