# Stacked grid BarChart3D

Tags: graphics3d, charts

I'm looking to use BarChart3D (in `"Grid"` mode) to show the elements of *two* real & positive matrices simultaneously. Since this will become a function in a library, I want to make it simple and extensible.

I plot a single matrix via:

```
BarChart3D[
    matrix1,

    ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
    Method -> {"Canvas" -> False}, 
    BarSpacing -> {.1, .1},
    ChartElementFunction -> Function[{xyz, z}, {
        Cuboid @@ Transpose @ xyz}]
 ]
```

which renders (as desired) like:

[image]

I now aim to plot the second matrix as semi-transparent cuboids stacked *above* the first matrix cuboids (showing only their difference; as if the second matrix were "under" the first, showing only its values greater than the first matrix's). This is similar to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96912/3d-plot-of-matrix-with-bars-overlayed-with-empty-bars), but with some important differences:

- In that question, the height of the transparent cuboids was fixed. Here, their height is element-dependent
- The location of my cuboids must be precisely centered at `(1,1)`, `(1,2)` ... etc for strict `x` and `y` labeling.

Something simple like `Show` doesn't work...

```
style = {ChartLayout -> "Grid", Method -> {"Canvas" -> False}, BarSpacing -> {.1, .1}}

Show[
    BarChart3D[
        matrix1,
        style,

        ChartElementFunction -> Function[{xyz, z},
            {Cuboid @@ Transpose@xyz}]
    ],
    BarChart3D[
        matrix2,
        style, 

        ChartElementFunction -> Function[{xyz, z},
            {Opacity[.2], Cuboid @@ Transpose@xyz}]
    ]
 ]
```

because the faces clip eachother:

[image]

The next obvious solution is to force the `Cuboid`s on a strict apriori-known grid (by `BarSpacing -> {0,0}`) and draw the transparent stacked cuboid myself.

```
(* will actually grab this from OptionValue[BarSpacing] *)
space  = .1;

BarChart3D[

    (* informs only (x,y) vals passed to ChartElementFuncion *)
    matrix1,

    ChartLayout -> "Grid",
    Method -> {"Canvas" -> False},

    (* force no spacing to keep (x,y) data on integer-grid *)
    BarSpacing -> {0, 0},

    ChartElementFunction -> Function[xyz,

        (*  take max (x,y) corner as center (cx,cy)=(i,j) *)
        With[
            {cx = xyz[[1, 2]], cy = xyz[[2, 2]], offset = -1/2 + space/2},
            {lx = cx + offset, rx = cx - offset,
             ly = cy + offset, ry = cy - offset, 
             z1 = matrix1[[ Round@cx, Round@cy]], 
             z2 = matrix2[[ Round@cx, Round@cy]]},

             {
                 (* draw matrix1 *)
                 Opacity[1], 
                 Cuboid[{lx, ly, 0}, {rx, ry, z1}],

                 (* draw matrix2 *)
                 If[z2 > z1, {
                     Opacity[.3], 
                     Cuboid[{lx, ly, 1.01 z1}, {rx, ry, z2}]}
                 ]
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

The result appears as desired...
[image]
but this makes customisation (e.g. of the colours) a bit awkward for the user. E.g. if they specify `ColorFunction -> "SolarColors"`, they'll see
[image]
that the `matrix1` colors are being determined by the `matrix2` values (when `matrix2 > matrix1`). Furthermore, I totally disregarded the `z` value that `BarChart3D` passed to `ChartElementFunction`, and looked up a different one in the matrices directly (which incidentally, doesn't match). This seems quite hacky, and I don't know whether it will bite me later.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: So we can reproduce, can you please add `matrix1`? If it is large, do this: `url = CloudPut[matrix1, Permissions->"Public"]` and paste in `CloudGet @ url`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a variant of your first approach, try just randomly shifting the positions of the bars a tiny bit that will be invisible to the human eye but will prevent the rendering collision effect. 
The following is just your code (with lines to generate fake data) and just the second Cuboid@@ slightly perturbed

```
matrix2 = DiagonalMatrix[Table[RandomReal[{0.8, 0.95}], {8}]];
matrix1 = 0.3*matrix2 + Table[RandomReal[{0, 0.2}], {8}, {8}];

style = {ChartLayout -> "Grid", Method -> {"Canvas" -> False}, BarSpacing -> {.1, .1}}

Show[
    BarChart3D[
        matrix1,
        style,

        ChartElementFunction -> Function[{xyz, z},
            {Cuboid @@ Transpose@xyz}]
    ],
    BarChart3D[
        matrix2,
        style, 

        ChartElementFunction -> Function[{xyz, z},
            {Opacity[.2], Cuboid @@ Transpose@(0.0015223 + 0.999123 xyz)}]
    ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is the only solution which worked without my library unexpectedly changing the user's frontend settings. Note in lieu of randomly perturbing the second BarChart's cuboids, one can just place them "slightly inside" the first BarChart's by a tiny margin

Answer (score 7):

The "face-clipping" artifacts in your second example are a common issue when rendering coplanar faces:

[image]

This problem is called [Z-Fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting), and luckily, it has an easy fix:

> Barchart[..., Method -> {"RelieveDPZFighting" -> True}]

Here's your code and with a few small changes:

```
matrix1 = Rescale @ Table[i+j,{i,8},{j,8}]//N;
matrix2 = matrix1+RandomReal[1,{8,8}]/2;
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}]; (* set this for best rendering *)
style = {Method -> {"RelieveDPZFighting"->True}, ChartLayout -> "Grid", BarSpacing -> {.1, .1}};
Show[
    BarChart3D[matrix1, ChartElementFunction -> Function[{xyz, z},
        {Cuboid @@ Transpose@xyz}], Sequence @@ style
    ],
    BarChart3D[matrix2, ChartElementFunction -> Function[{xyz, z},
        {Opacity[.2], Cuboid @@ Transpose@xyz}], Sequence @@ style
    ],
    ViewPoint -> {-2,-3,1}, ViewAngle -> 16\[Degree], ImageSize -> {800,500}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/1.8}, PlotRangePadding -> 0
]
```

[image]

Comment: `Method -> {"RelieveDPZFighting"->True}` has no effect on the clipping I see (I'm on MacOS if this matters). It *is* resolved by modifying the front-end rendering options (regardless of `RelieveDPZFighting` or not), but I feel I should avoid this in a library under the principle of least astonishment

Comment: I should point out too that this doesn't achieve the result of "`matrix2` cuboids stacked *above* `matrix1` since even when transparent here, the 'top' cuboids effect the colouring of the `matrix1` cuboids beanath them (evident when coloured different, e.g. by respective `ColorFunction`s.

Comment: (my ability to edit expired, hmph): I can avoid this by slightly shrinking the x-y size of the `matrix2` cuboids (so they hide within the `matrix1` cuboids) in `ChartEllementFunction`, though it's a small inelegance

Answer (score 2):

If `matrix1` and `matrix2` have non-negative entries, you can also construct [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) objects and use [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html):

```
SeedRandom[1]
matrix1 = Rescale@Table[i + j, {i, 8}, {j, 8}] // N;
matrix2 = matrix1 + RandomReal[1, {8, 8}]/2;

{wd1, wd2} = WeightedData[Join @@ Array[List, Dimensions @ #], 
     Join @@ #] & /@ {matrix1, matrix2};

Histogram3D[{wd1, wd2},  ChartStyle -> {Opacity[1], Opacity[.3]}, 
 Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range[8], CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[;; 8]]}], Range[8], Automatic}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> ({EdgeForm[{Thin, Gray}], 
      Blend[System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultGradient, #2[[1, 1]]/8],
       ChartElementData["Cube"][{{.1, -.1}, {.1, -.1}, {0, 0}} + #, #2]}&), 
 ImageSize -> Large, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]
```

[image]

Comment: This seems the most natural way to achieve the plot, and cleanly separate the styles of the two matrices. However, it has the same face-clipping problem that M. R. addresses in his solution (also ineffective here)

Comment: Ah and by virtue of being the 'right' way, has the limitation of being able to specify a single `ColorFunction`, whereas I can 'split up' a user's `ColorFunction -> {f1, f2}` myself if I use a `Show` solution

Comment: Note the user must supply the number-of-bins arg to `Histogram3D`, or suddenly (for >=16-by-16 matrices) bars will stack